# Solution when super cannot be first line of constructor in java

Tags: java

I am using a CSVReader class that takes a local file as input. But now, I need to be able to read local files as well as files having a URL path (like http://example.com/example.txt). To do this, I want to derive a class from CSVReader that identifies whether the file is local or URL, and then pass the InputStream to the parent using super() in the first line of the constructor. What is the elegant way of doing this ?

```
public class FileReader extends CsvReader{
    public FileReader(){
        if (fileName != null) {

               if (fileName.trim().startsWith("http:")) {
                // it is URL
                URL url = new URL(fileName);
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        url.openStream(), charset),
                        StaticSettings.MAX_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE); 
               }else{
                //it is a local file
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(fileName), charset),
                        StaticSettings.MAX_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE);
               } 

            }
            //Now pass the input stream to CsvReader
            super(inputStream, delimiter, charset);  //error - super has to be first line of constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't call your classes the same names as well-known classes in the JDK. You are going to cause someone great confusion, very possibly yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write auxiliary methods:

```
super(createReader(createInputStream(resouce), "UTF-8"), ";");
```

Your auxiliary method might look like this:

```
public static InputStream createInputStream(String resource)
{
     resource = resource.trim();

     if (resource.startsWith("http:"))
     {
          return new URL(resource).openStream();
     } else
     {
          return new FileInputStream(new File(resource));
     }
}

public static BufferedReader createReader(InputStream is, String charset)
{
     return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));
}
```

Comment: The method `constructInputStream` must be declared `static`.

Answer (score 7):

You can declare your constructor as `private`, and create a factory static method, which will do the checking before invoking the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Move the code to compute the arguments to `super()` to a static function, and call it inside `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to include static method that will create all necessary stuff and then call the constructor:

```
public class FileReader extends CsvReader
{
    public static FileReader createFileReader(String filename, String delimiter, String charset){
        if (fileName != null) {
           BufferedReader inputStream;
           if (fileName.trim().startsWith("http:")) {
               // it is URL
               URL url = new URL(fileName);
               inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset), StaticSettings.MAX_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE); 
           }
           else
           {
                //it is a local file
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), charset), StaticSettings.MAX_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE);
           } 
           return new FileReader(inputStream, delimiter, charset);
       }
       return null;
    }

    public FileReader(BufferedReader inputStream, String delimiter, String charset){
            super(inputStream, delimiter, charset);
    }
}
```