# error on using super() in java

Tags: java, android

```
public class DriveActivity extends Activity {
    void method_195(DriveActivity var1) {
        this.this$0 = var1;
        super();
     }

    void method_206(DriveActivity var1) {
        this.this$0 = var1;
        super();
     }

     public void onClick(View var1) {
        if(TimerService.modeNum < TimerService.modeCount) {
           ++TimerService.modeNum;
        } else {
           TimerService.modeNum = 1;
        }

        DriveActivity.access$11(this.this$0).setText(Integer.toString(TimerService.modeNum));
        this.this$0.drive_stop();
        DriveActivity.access$12(this.this$0);
     }
  };
  var3.method_206(this);
```

Why I cant use super inside this method? its stated that 
"Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"

Comment: var3.method_206(this); also give me error on undefined

Comment: Answer is there in the question it self.

Comment: because super constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor.

Comment: Redundant question is redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is calling super() constructor should be the very first line of the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727601/is-calling-super-constructor-should-be-the-very-first-line-of-the-constructor)

Answer (score 3):

```
void method_206(DriveActivity var1) {
    this.this$0 = var1;
    super();
 }
```

You are trying to call the super class constructor from a method, that is wrong.`super()` can be used only inside a constructor and it has to be the first statement in the constructor.

Comment: How many answers do you post for the same question

Comment: As much as the SO allows me to ;)

Comment: But why posting new answer if you can just [edit] old one?

Comment: Because I was not able to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16760656/edit). Something was wrong when I tried to edit , didn't allow me to.

Comment: I just edited your previous answer and it seems to work fine (at least now). Strange... What could be the problem? Did you see any information from system when you pressed "save edits" button?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `super()` inside a method. As the error states:

> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

If you want to use it, it must be **inside a constructor** and at the **first line**.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is completely redundant since the error message is telling you *exactly* what the problem is (*"Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"*) the reason for this is because the [Java Language Specification section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.7) explicitly defines the structure of a constructor:

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct superclass (§8.8.7.1).

```
ConstructorBody:
    { ExplicitConstructorInvocationopt BlockStatementsopt }
```